# Haskell input list - recursive on list

Tags: haskell

i want the user to give the size of the list and then use that list in other function. Something like that

```
divv x = [x..2]

qsort       :: [Int] -> [Int]    
qsort []     = []    
qsort (x:xs) =    
   qsort smaller ++ [x] ++ qsort larger    
   where    
      smaller = [a | a <- xs, a <= x]    
      larger  = [b | b <- xs, b > x]
```

When i write in the console divv 10 i'll get the list [10..2]
When i write qsort[1,2,8,5,3,9,0] i'll get the list sorted.

I want the user to give just a number for example 100 and then to call qsort (divv 100).
How can i make this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `divv x = [x,(x-1)..2]` produces [10,9,8,...2] for x == 10

Comment: you need to define a new function, `fun n = qsort (divv n)`. then you just call it, `fun 100`. You can also write `(\n -> qsort (divv n)) 100` or `(\n -> (qsort . divv) n) 100` or `(qsort . divv) 100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read input from terminal, you can use `getLine :: IO String`. Before passing the string to your function, however, you will need to convert it into an integral type (in this case, an `Int`). You can do this using the function `read :: Read a => String -> a`. To print a string, you can use the function `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`. Before printing `qsort (divv n)`, however, you will need to convert its result into a string. This is done using the function `show :: Show a => a -> String`.

Putting everything together, you first want to `getLine` a string, say `s`. Next, you want to `read` that string into an `Int`, say `n`. Finally, you want to use `putStrLn` to print the result of calling `show` on the list `qsort (divv n)`. In order to *sequence* these actions, you will require the `bind` operation in the `IO` monad, or else `do` notation (which just desugars to monadic combinators like `bind`). Here is an example implementation. As an exercise, try translating this implementation into `do` notation:

```
sortList :: IO ()
sortList = fmap read getLine >>= putStrLn . show . qsort . divv
```

Note that your implementation of `divv` is incorrect. It should read `divv n = [n,n-1..2]` (in order to generate a list of integers from `n` to `2` in descending order). Also note that there are probably better ways to accomplish the task of asking a user for input, and returning the result of applying that input to some function. But this is the easiest, in my opinion.